# jQuery, associative array and binding events

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, closures

I would like to bind the same event to 3 checkboxes but with a different target each time:

```
  var checkboxes = {
    'selector1' : 'target1',
    'selector2' : 'target2',
    'selector3' : 'target3',
  };

  for (selector in checkboxes) {
    var target = checkboxes[selector];

    if (jQuery(selector).is(':checked')) {
      jQuery(target).show();
    }
    else {
      jQuery(target).hide();
    }

    jQuery(selector).bind('change', function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        jQuery(target).show();
      }
      else {
        jQuery(target).hide();
      }
    });
  };
```

But it doesn't work: on "change", the 3 selectors show/hide the 3rd target.

Comment: That construct `{'key': 'value'...}` is called an _Object Literal_ in JavaScript, not an associative array.

Comment: What do `target1`, etc refer to? Checkbox id attributes?

Comment: @Michael: Well, the syntax is called an object literal. The code creates an object, which is an associative array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the code in the event handler will use the variable `target`, not the value of the variable as it was when the event handler was created. When the event hander runs, the variable will contain the last value used in the loop.

Use an anonymous function to create a closure, that captures the value of the variable:

```
for (selector in checkboxes) {
  var target = checkboxes[selector];

  if (jQuery(selector).is(':checked')) {
    jQuery(target).show();
  } else {
    jQuery(target).hide();
  }

  (function(target){

    jQuery(selector).bind('change', function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        jQuery(target).show();
      } else {
        jQuery(target).hide();
      }
    });

  })(target);

};
```

Side note: You can use the `toggle` method to make the code simpler:

```
for (selector in checkboxes) {
  var target = checkboxes[selector];

  jQuery(target).toggle(jQuery(selector).is(':checked'));

  (function(target){

    jQuery(selector).bind('change', function() {
      jQuery(target).toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
    });

  })(target);

};
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works nice (and thanks for the toggle too)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because `target` isn't scoped inside of a function.  Blocks DO NOT provide scope in javascript.

But I've reduced it down for you and hopefully this will work out:

```
$.each(checkboxes, function(selector, target) {
   $(selector).change(function () {
       $(target).toggle($(selector).is(':checked'));
   }).trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: Provided of course that there is no other code that uses the change event on those elements, as you trigger the event when there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

`target` scope is the problem !

You could have simpler code:

- use data for the handler
- use `.toggle(condition)`

  ```
  $.each(checkboxes, function(selector, target) {
      $(selector).on('change', {target:target}, function (evt) {
          $(evt.data.target).toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
      }).change();
  });
  ```

Comment: Provided of course that there is no other code that uses the change event on those elements, as you trigger the event when there is no change.